# How to fetch current value of _version for a document

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

How to fetch current value of _version  for a document using spring-data-elasticsearch API(s)

```
   {
      "_index" : "foos",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "FQOO93sBMpiRC0Jqlyn8",
      "_version" : 3,
      "result" : "updated",
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 2,
        "successful" : 1,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "_seq_no" : 84,
      "_primary_term" : 2
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your entity define a property that is annotated with `@Version`:

```java
@Document(indexName="foos")
class Foo {
    @Id private String id;
    @Version private Long version;
    // other properties, getter and setter
}
```

when returning entities in get or search results, this property will be populated with the version value.

Comment: will the index mapping change because of this, since we have the app is already in production

Comment: No. the version is not persisted to the _source of a document and so it does not appear in the mapping